# Creating Custom Texture

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

Need some help with a custom texture that I want to create. Reference texture (want to achieve something like this) I found on the web:
[image]

I tried to create something similar with the following node set up:
[image]

But the result I get does not have those sharp radial spikes:
[image]

Any advice on how to get those sharp radial spikes..?? Playing around with the Roughness/Detail and Distortion of the Noise node does not give the desired result...Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Gradient: Radial to get a polar coordinate, then based on it generate a random value:

[image]

[image]

you can similarly design an outer side of the 'rim', and switch between the shading of the two based on the sign of the signed distance (Math: Greater Than → Mix'es Factor).

Of course that's just the beginning, you probably want to add some variation by e.g. warping the coordinates like so:

[image]